# NameError : name 's' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I am trying to create a class which only allows to objects to be created. I am using a private variable instance to keep track of count .
My Code -

```
class s:
    __instance=2

    if s.__instance<2:
        def __init__(self,x):
            s._instance = x
            s._instance = s._instance+1
            print(s._instance)

a=s(5)
```

When i run the code i got -

```
"C:\Users\PIYU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/PIYU/PycharmProjects/PythonProgram/singleton.py"
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/PIYU/PycharmProjects/PythonProgram/singleton.py", line 1, in <module>
    class s:
    File "C:/Users/PIYU/PycharmProjects/PythonProgram/singleton.py", line 4, in s
    if s.__instance<2:
    NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

Comment: It's a duplicate of quite a few other questions here but I can't find one right now - if someone does please vote to close the question.

Comment: Relevant [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax).

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers With all respect I gone through all the similar questions sir. When i was unable to find an answer i asked

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds assigning to `self.__instance` in the `__init__` will create an instance attribute, it will not assign to the class attribute.

Comment: @shantanunandan  I'm not blaming you - the fact that I have a hard time finding a relevant duplicate (while I know tens of questions relating to the very same problem have already been posted) speaks for itself actually.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yeah I deleted my comment, I misread the question. OP, check out the Python docs on the Singleton pattern [here](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__)

Comment: @bruno desthuilliers Thanks for your help sir.

Comment: @shantanunandan What is your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because you are trying to reference `s` in it's own definition, before it is actually defined. I would try using that condition in `__init__` instead of before it.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds for what the OP is trying to do, using a class attribute makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `class` is an executable statement that creates a new `class` class object and bind it to the class name in the enclosing scope. Until the whole statement has been executed (IOW until the end of the `class` statement block), the class object doesn't exist and the name is not defined.

To make things clearer, this:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 42
    def foo(self):
        print "foo"
```

is actually only syntactic sugar for

```
def foo(self):
    print "foo"

Foo = type("Foo", (object,), {"foo": foo, "bar": 42})
del foo  # remove the name from current scope
```

Comment: I believe it is still possible to reference the class inside itself, you just have to be careful with the ordering of your statements inside the block. [E.g.](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558-the-singleton-pattern-implemented-with-python/)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds you can reference the class from within methods. You __can not__ reference it within the `class` statement block, period.

Comment: Ah I see, the `class` block scope does not extend to methods.